# How to improve the performance of this query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, query-tuning

I have broken my head to try to create indices, or change mysql configuration to improve a query but I'm not getting it. Could someone help me?

I am creating a system that has more than four million products and to improve the response time for the User, I am creating a materialized view.

To create this view I use the query below

```
INSERT into 
    consulta_atual 
SELECT 
    fc.cd_categoria, 
    tbc.cd_categoria as cd_categoria_site, 
    tbc.nm_categoria, 
    fc.ds_subcategoria, ppf.cd_produto_price,
    ppf2.cd_seq,
    f.tp_fornecedor as tp_fornecedor ,
    pp.nm_produto as name,
    pp.nm_slug as nm_slug,
    pf.cd_fornecedor as fornecedor,
    f.url_img_fornecedor as url_img_fornecedor,
    f.url_raiz_fornecedor as url_raiz_fornecedor,
    pf.url_imagem as url_imagem,
    concat(IFNULL(pf.url_produto_fornecedor_prefix,''),pf.url_produto_fornecedor,IFNULL(pf.url_produto_fornecedor_sufix,'')) as url_produto,
    CONCAT('R$ ', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(ppf.vlr_produto, 2),'.',';'),',','.'),';',',')) as vlr_produto,
    CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(ppf.vlr_produto, 0),'.',';'),',','.'),';',','),' pontos') as pnt_produto,
    ppf.vlr_produto as vlr_produto_original,
    null,
    null,
    null 
FROM 
    produto_price pp,
    produto_fornecedor pf,
    preco_produto_fornecedor ppf,
    fornecedores f,
    fornecedores_categorias fc,
    vw_preco_atual ppf2,
    tb_st_category tbc 
WHERE 
        pp.cd_produto = pf.cd_produto_price 
    AND pf.cd_categoria = fc.cd_categoria 
    AND fc.cd_categoria_site = tbc.cd_categoria 
    AND pp.cd_produto = ppf2.cd_produto_price 
    AND pf.cd_fornecedor = f.cd_fornecedor 
    AND pf.cd_fornecedor = ppf2.cd_fornecedor 
    AND ppf2.cd_seq = ppf.cd_seq
```

However, with the passage of time, and increasing product it is taking about 4 hours to this table being created. Is it possible to improve shifting performance indices of the tables or configuration?

script create tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consulta_atual` (
  `cd_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cd_categoria_site` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_categoria` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ds_subcategoria` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `cd_produto_price` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `cd_seq` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tp_fornecedor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `nm_slug` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fornecedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url_img_fornecedor` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `url_raiz_fornecedor` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `url_imagem` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `url_produto` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `vlr_produto` varchar(49) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pnt_produto` varchar(53) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vlr_produto_original` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `menor_valor` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `maior_valor` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtd_lojas` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cd_produto_price`,`fornecedor`),
  KEY `nm_slug_2` (`nm_slug`),
  KEY `ds_categoria` (`ds_categoria`),
  KEY `vlr_produto_original` (`vlr_produto_original`),
  KEY `cd_categoria_site` (`cd_categoria_site`),
  KEY `fornecedor` (`fornecedor`),
  KEY `tp_fornecedor` (`tp_fornecedor`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ds_categoria_2` (`ds_categoria`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ds_categoria_3` (`ds_categoria`,`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fornecedores` (
  `cd_fornecedor` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nm_fornecedor` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tp_fornecedor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url_img_fornecedor` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `dt_atualizacao` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `url_raiz_fornecedor` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cd_fornecedor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fornecedores_categorias` (
  `cd_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cd_fornecedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cd_categoria_site` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Referencia a Categoria do SIte',
  `ds_categoria` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `url_categoria` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `cd_prioridade` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ds_subcategoria` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`url_categoria`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cd_categoria` (`cd_categoria`),
  KEY `ds_categoria` (`ds_categoria`),
  KEY `cd_categoria_site` (`cd_categoria_site`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6112 ;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `preco_produto_fornecedor` (
  `cd_seq` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cd_produto_price` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `cd_fornecedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dt_atualizacao` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `vlr_produto` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `flg_sucesso` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cd_seq`,`cd_produto_price`,`cd_fornecedor`),
  KEY `dt_atualizacao` (`dt_atualizacao`),
  KEY `cd_fornecedor` (`cd_fornecedor`),
  KEY `vlr_produto` (`vlr_produto`),
  KEY `cd_produto_price` (`cd_produto_price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=151452428 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produto_fornecedor` (
  `cd_produto_price` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `ds_produto` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cd_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url_produto_fornecedor` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `url_produto_fornecedor_prefix` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Url Afiliados ANTES',
  `url_produto_fornecedor_sufix` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Url Afiliados DEPOIS',
  `url_imagem` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `cd_fornecedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `flg_ativo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `dt_atualizacao` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cd_produto_price`,`cd_fornecedor`),
  KEY `ds_produto_2` (`ds_produto`(333))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produto_price` (
  `cd_produto` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nm_produto` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `nm_slug` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cd_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cd_produto`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nm_produto_2` (`nm_produto`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nm_slug_2` (`nm_slug`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `nm_produto` (`nm_produto`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3861158 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_st_category` (
  `cd_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nm_categoria` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ds_categoria` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_img_categoria` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nm_slug` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Nome amigavel da categoria para poder indexar no google',
  `flg_menu_topo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Flag para aparecer ou nao no menu do site',
  `flg_categoria_especial` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Flag para aparecer com prioridade (Ex.: Categoria de Natal)',
  `cd_categoria_pai` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Se tiver com numero maior que 0 é uma subcategoria',
  `flg_ativo` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 desativado 1 ativo',
  `dt_cadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'data que foi criado a categoria',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cd_categoria`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ds_categoria` (`ds_categoria`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=437 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vw_preco_atual` (
  `cd_produto_price` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `cd_fornecedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cd_seq` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cd_fornecedor`,`cd_produto_price`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cd_seq` (`cd_seq`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: why are you selecting null values? Can't you just ignore them?

Comment: By the way, there's a CONCAT_WS function. I think you might like it. And it's incredibly unlikely that you wanted FLOAT here. See DECIMAL.

Comment: null values are replaced later by another query, but this update is fast.

Comment: the concat command is necessary to format the value to show to final user.. i think the problem of performance is the joins and yours indexes

Answer (score 0):

replace commands in the query are very expensive. Try to reduce them as much as possible. Index the fields used the where condition

I see you do insert the resultset in another table. So the records already inserted, do not need to be processed again. So best way is to run this query for the newly created records using the timestamp. If you don't have timestamps, introduce them newly. Once you process records upto a time, store it somewhere. And start from that time to current time. In this way of batching, you reduce the unnecessary time with the old records..

Comment: i truncate the table in every load. because the values not are same

Comment: The replace commands in the query are very expensive. Try to reduce them as much as possible. Index the fields used the where condition.

Comment: "every load" -- Are you saying that you rebuild the base tables periodically?  And hence, it would be awkward to see which rows have changed or not changed?